# What's the exact solutions of the differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

When I solve the Dirac equation in some special external field, I meet a strange differential equation, which is an angular equation
$$(\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}+\epsilon_\phi\frac{\pm\cos\theta-\epsilon_\phi}{\sin^2 \theta}+\epsilon^2_\theta)\Theta^\pm_s=0$$
when we take $\cos\theta=x, \Theta_s=y(x)$, energy components of angular direction $\epsilon_\phi=a, \epsilon_\theta=b$, we can get the abstract form

$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2}-x\frac{d y(x)}{d x}-\frac{a(x\pm a) y(x)}{1-x^2}+b^2y(x) =0$$
There is a natural constraint: y(x) must be finite when $x\in[−1,1]$, for the angular component of wavefunction $\Theta_s$ must be finite. At the same time, we have a periodic boundary condition: $y(-1)=y(1)$. It's from $\Theta_s(0)=\Theta_s(\pi)$, for the wavefunctions' periodic property.

Then I use the Mathematica to do a rough calculate, which tells me the solution of the equation are hypergeometric functions. But actually, what I care is the eigenvalue $b$ in this equation.

**Question**

1.What the exact form of $b$ is?

2.What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$?

**Thanks**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"What the exact form of "b" in the equation is?"* As written, it appears to be just a parameter, what's the question?

Comment: Do you have any boundary conditions on this?

Comment: @Rellek There is a natural boundary condition:y(x) must be finite when $x\in[-1,1]$.